# Azure on TFS 2010 best practics

Tags: tfs, azure

I'm trying to get our TFS server to build a solution with an azure project. To get up to speed fast, I installed the azure SDK 1.6 on the build server/agent. I only needs to build and not publish  the project for the moment. But I get the error below.

The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Both the development machine and the build agent is x64, but on the development machine the azure stuff was installed in to "programfiles (x86).

Now I really need an advice on how to get the build agent to build the project, do I really need to include some dll's in the project, or how do I best fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up and running. A quick and dirty installation of the azure sdk and azure tools for visual studio did the trick.